# Why is udp packet, sent by dpdk, received with zero'd payload?

Tags: dpdk

I am running dpdk-stable-18.11.8 on Centos 7. My test code transmits udp packets with a simple payload string 'Hello from dpdk' to a remote host.

Immediately before transmission a dump of the mbuf looks like this:

```
dump mbuf at 0x53e4e92c0, iova=73e4e9340, buf_len=2176
  pkt_len=57, ol_flags=c0000000000000, nb_segs=2, in_port=65535
  segment at 0x53e4e92c0, data=0x53e4e9396, data_len=42
  Dump data at [0x53e4e9396], len=42
00000000: 94 40 C9 1F C4 DB 94 40 C9 1E 13 7D 08 00 45 B8 | .@.....@...}..E.
00000010: 00 2B 00 00 00 00 40 11 F5 E8 C0 A8 01 69 C0 A8 | .+....@......i..
00000020: 01 68 0B B9 0B B8 00 17 64 2D |  |  |  |  |  |  | .h......d-
  segment at 0x53e146e40, data=0x53e4fbbc0, data_len=15
  Dump data at [0x53e4fbbc0], len=15
00000000: 48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 66 72 6F 6D 20 64 70 64 6B |  | Hello from dpdk
```

Running tcpdump with command:

```
tcpdump -A -nni eno2 src 192.168.1.105 -vv -X
```

on the remote host yields:

```
10:44:33.022538 IP (tos 0xb8, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 43)
    192.168.1.105.3001 > 192.168.1.104.3000: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 15
        0x0000:  45b8 002b 0000 0000 4011 f5e8 c0a8 0169  E..+....@......i
        0x0010:  c0a8 0168 0bb9 0bb8 0017 642d 0000 0000  ...h......d-....
        0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
```

So the udp packet arrives but the payload is all zeros.

(The transmitter is 192.168.1.105 and the receiver is 192.168.1.104).

Here's a snippet of my code that adds space for the udp and ip headers to the mbuf in the transmitter:

```
p_udp_hdr = (struct udp_hdr*)rte_pktmbuf_prepend(ptMbuf, (uint16_t)sizeof(struct udp_hdr));
p_ip_hdr  = (struct ipv4_hdr*)rte_pktmbuf_prepend(ptMbuf, (uint16_t)sizeof(struct ipv4_hdr));
```

I'm not sure where to look, as the code is adapted from working code from another project. It may be relevant that, in the other project, checksums were generated by the NIC but in this project I have calculated them in software; but tcpdump says the checksums are correct.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @DavidA requesting you to check the dev_configure TX offload flag for multi-segment behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable multi segments in the eth_dev configuration as indicated
below:

```
.txmode = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    .offloads = DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_MULTI_SEGS,                                                                                                                                                                                                                               },
```

[EDIT-1] also shared in comment 'Hi @DavidA requesting you to check the dev_configure TX offload flag for multi-segment behaviour. '.

Answer (score 0):

I believe at least part of your problem is that, while you've modified the pkt_len field in your packet to reflect the payload you've added, data_len is still just 42 bytes.  That's just the length of your L2-4 headers.  You want to add space for your payload there as well.

Also, I note that the nb_segs field in your packet is 2, indicating that you have a chain of packets.  Do you?  I wouldn't expect having that wrong would cause the problem you're seeing, but it's probably something you'd like to fix up, regardless.

[EDIT-2] Issue because PKT_TX_MSEGS is not updated in application. Refelcted in above answer and comment `Hi @DavidA requesting you to check the dev_configure TX offload flag for multi-segment behaviour. – Vipin Varghese Jul 2 '20 at 12:13`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't know much about dpdk but I think it may be ok that I have two segments because the mbuf initially contained just the payload (15 chars) and then I prepended the Ethernet and L3 headers (additional 42 bytes). So the total length is 57 chars, which is correct. Perhaps the first (payload) segment is not getting transmitted?

Comment: OK, so you do have a chain of packets.  Given that, I don't see why you're pretending at all.  Are you calling rte_pktmbuf_prepend() on the packet with the payload?  If so, you're moving the data pointer up by sizeof(IP header + UDP header) in front of your content, and that's your problem.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm doing: put the payload in a mbuf then prepend to add the udp header and prepend to add the ip header. That appeared to worked ok in the example (inhouse code) that I am following. Are you saying that is wrong? Do you know of an example that shows how to do it properly?

Comment: Two ways to do it:
1. Just have one packet that has both the headers and payload.  If you're starting with an mbuf with just the payload, you should prepend space for the headers, put them in the same mbuf as the content, and send.
2. Have one packet with the headers and a second with the payload.  Just write the headers in one mbuf, the payload in the other, link them up and send.

It feels as though you're halfway in between those two.  So you have a packet with headers and one with content, but you've prepended on the content one, so you read from the a spot 42 bytes earlier in the mbuf

Comment: @SynAckRst answer shared is not correct, can you please cross the TX_OFFLOAD flags necessary to transmit multi-segments?